# installing file on remote machine with GUI

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

whenever an .exe file is executed on remote machine with help of `pssession` and `invoke-command` with `start-process`..
it the execuable runs in background , i am able to see the process in task manager but cpu alloted to that process is 0% and also it keeps running.

i want to pop up GUI of executable file on remote machine whenever i run script.

i tried..
1)

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\scripts\dbsetup_trial.exe' -ArgumentList '/S' -PassThru -Verb runas}
```

2) by enetring in `PSsession`, i tried executing exe, bt result was same.
please help me out.

i need to install file , if silent installation is option it should install file silently or just pop the window of executable and return back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot invoke a GUI on a remote system's interactive session via PowerShell. PowerShell remote sessions are unable to interact with other sessions, especially the logged-on user session(s).

`psexec` can do this, but the better way to do this is to run a silent/unattended install if it's an option with that application installer. We can't answer that because we don't know what that installer is or how it's made.